# keep getting transaction failed when trying to do pancake swap transactions in nodejs with web3 and ethersjs

Tags: solidity, web3js, ethers.js

error message (code attached below)

```
node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\lib\index.js:180
        var error = new Error(message);
                    ^

Error: transaction failed (transactionHash="0x03e0911d26d2175d55b233b4a7b17d06202e7c2fb52a2ecfd35f3863814cb374", transaction={"nonce":364,"gasPrice":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x02540be400"},"gasLimit":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x7a1200"},"to":"0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E","value":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x00"},"data":"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","chainId":56,"v":147,"r":"0xc1a926e6f3989a50185b2d75c4bc877a76c8a2f30d505a1055fa89271feba035","s":"0x0ebeb2da65954541c82ddf468177cc6a49324a0e7a6e3fb3f5795f41c1055261","from":"0x3975383Df42Df8ED045d636b255Bf0829d8D5970","hash":"0x03e0911d26d2175d55b233b4a7b17d06202e7c2fb52a2ecfd35f3863814cb374","type":null}, receipt={"to":"0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E","from":"0x3975383Df42Df8ED045d636b255Bf0829d8D5970","contractAddress":null,"transactionIndex":19,"gasUsed":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x5a67"},"logsBloom":"0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","blockHash":"0xd504dfc3e7703e7657239e04f0d36e8118633689395cfc6fb9b3d6f213893724","transactionHash":"0x03e0911d26d2175d55b233b4a7b17d06202e7c2fb52a2ecfd35f3863814cb374","logs":[],"blockNumber":7497373,"confirmations":1,"cumulativeGasUsed":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x216ce6"},"status":0,"byzantium":true}, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=providers/5.1.2)
    at Logger.makeError (D:\codeforFun\322-uniswap-trading-bot\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\lib\index.js:180:21)
    at Logger.throwError (D:\codeforFun\322-uniswap-trading-bot\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\lib\index.js:189:20)
    at JsonRpcProvider.<anonymous> (D:\codeforFun\322-uniswap-trading-bot\node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\lib\base-provider.js:1162:36)
    at step (D:\codeforFun\322-uniswap-trading-bot\node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\lib\base-provider.js:48:23)
    at Object.next (D:\codeforFun\322-uniswap-trading-bot\node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\lib\base-provider.js:29:53)
    at fulfilled (D:\codeforFun\322-uniswap-trading-bot\node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\lib\base-provider.js:20:58)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:94:5) {
```

code, get from [here](https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/im-trying-to-execute-swap-on-pancakeswap-with-web3-js-but-i-get-error/8379)

```
const ethers = require('ethers');

const {ChainId, Token, TokenAmount, Fetcher, Pair, Route, Trade, TradeType, Percent} = 

require('@pancakeswap-libs/sdk');

const Web3 = require('web3');

const {JsonRpcProvider} = require("@ethersproject/providers");

require("dotenv").config();

const provider = new JsonRpcProvider('https://bsc-dataseed1.binance.org/');

const web3 = new Web3('wss://apis.ankr.com/wss/c40792ffe3514537be9fb4109b32d257/946dd909d324e5a6caa2b72ba75c5799/binance/full/main');

const { address: admin } = web3.eth.accounts.wallet.add(process.env.PRIVATE_KEY);

console.log(`Modulos cargados`);

// Command Line Input

const InputTokenAddr = web3.utils.toChecksumAddress(process.argv[2]);

// var BUSD = '0xe9e7CEA3DedcA5984780Bafc599bD69ADd087D56';

const OutputTokenAddr = web3.utils.toChecksumAddress(process.argv[3]);

// var WBNB = '0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c';

const InputTokenAmount = process.argv[4]

const Slipage = process.argv[5];

const PANCAKE_ROUTER = process.argv[6];

// const PANCAKE_ROUTER_V2 = '0x10ed43c718714eb63d5aa57b78b54704e256024e';

// const PANCAKE_ROUTER_V1 = '0x05fF2B0DB69458A0750badebc4f9e13aDd608C7F';

// 1/1000 = 0.001

const ONE_ETH_IN_WEI = web3.utils.toBN(web3.utils.toWei('1'));//BN->(BIG NUMBER) || toWei -> Converts any ether value value into wei.

const tradeAmount = ONE_ETH_IN_WEI.div(web3.utils.toBN('1000'));//tradeAmount = ONE_ETH_IN_WEI/1000

console.log(`tradeAmount ` + tradeAmount );

const init = async () => {

    const [INPUT_TOKEN, OUTPUT_TOKEN] = await Promise.all(

        [InputTokenAddr, OutputTokenAddr].map(tokenAddress => (

            new Token(

                ChainId.MAINNET,

                tokenAddress,

                18

            )

        )));

    console.log(` <<<<<------- pair-------->>>>>`);

    const pair = await Fetcher.fetchPairData(INPUT_TOKEN, OUTPUT_TOKEN, provider);

    //console.log(JSON.stringify(pair));

    console.log(` <<<<<------- route-------->>>>>`);

    const route = await new Route([pair], INPUT_TOKEN);

    //console.log(JSON.stringify(route));

    console.log(` <<<<<------- Trade-------->>>>>`);

    const trade = await new Trade(route, new TokenAmount(INPUT_TOKEN, tradeAmount), TradeType.EXACT_INPUT);

    //console.log(JSON.stringify(trade));

    //https://uniswap.org/docs/v2/javascript-SDK/trading/

    const slippageTolerance = new Percent(Slipage, '100'); // 

    console.log("slippageTolerance: " + JSON.stringify(slippageTolerance));

    // create transaction parameters

    const amountOutMin = trade.minimumAmountOut(slippageTolerance).raw;

    const path = [INPUT_TOKEN.address, OUTPUT_TOKEN.address];

    const to = admin;

    const deadline = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60 * 20;

    // Create signer

    const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(

        Buffer.from(

        process.env.PRIVATE_KEY, 

        "hex"

        )

    );

    const signer = wallet.connect(provider);

    // Create Pancakeswap ethers Contract

    const pancakeswap = new ethers.Contract(

        PANCAKE_ROUTER,

        ['function swapExactTokensForTokens(uint amountIn, uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline) external returns (uint[] memory amounts)'],

        signer

    );

    //Allow input token

    if(true)

    {

        console.log(`Allow Pancakeswap <<<<<------- START-------->>>>>`);

        let abi = ["function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success)"];

        let contract = new ethers.Contract(INPUT_TOKEN.address, abi, signer);

        let aproveResponse = await contract.approve(PANCAKE_ROUTER, ethers.utils.parseUnits('1000.0', 18), {gasLimit: 100000, gasPrice: 5e9});

        console.log(JSON.stringify(aproveResponse));

        console.log(`Allow Pancakeswap <<<<<------- END-------->>>>>`);

        

    }

    

    if(true)

    {   

        console.log(`Ejecutando transaccion`);      

        var amountInParam = ethers.utils.parseUnits(InputTokenAmount, 18);

        var amountOutMinParam = ethers.utils.parseUnits(web3.utils.fromWei(amountOutMin.toString()), 18);

        

        console.log("amountInParam: " + amountInParam);

        console.log("amountOutMinParam: " + amountOutMinParam);

        console.log("amountOutMin: " + amountOutMin);

                        

        const tx = await pancakeswap.swapExactTokensForTokens(

            amountInParam,

            amountOutMinParam,

            path,

            to,

            deadline,

            { gasLimit: ethers.utils.hexlify(300000), gasPrice: ethers.utils.parseUnits("9", "gwei") }

        );

        console.log(`Tx-hash: ${tx.hash}`)

            const receipt = await tx.wait();

            console.log(`Tx was mined in block: ${receipt.blockNumber}`);

    }

        

}

init();
```